# Encoding pair in lambda calculus

Tags: lambda-calculus

I am confused about the logic behind how lambda calculus encodes the pair data structure.

In lambda calculus, PAIR is encoded as

> PAIR := λx.λy.λf. f x y

.

Why can't I just encode it as

> PAIR := λx.λy. x y

or

> PAIR := λf.λx.λy. f x y

?

What is the design choice when doing such encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given two arguments `x, y`, the `pair` function is supposed to take a new function `f` and apply it to the "pair" of arguments. I will try to give an intuitive view, now let's see what your examples do:

```
λx.λy. x y
```

This function takes two arguments, and passes the second (`y`) as an argument to the first (`x`). So this is just function application.

```
λf.λx.λy. f x y
```

On the surface this looks similar to the original, but it has an issue. Here we get the function to which the two arguments are gonna be supplied to as the *first* argument. This means it is not possible to actually *store* the two arguments `x,y`, which is why the original is the version that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

This is known as [Church pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Church_pairs).

One should keep in mind that `pair` and `PAIR` are not the same thing.

- `PAIR` *build* a pair: given two arguments, `PAIR` return `pair`
- `pair` allow to retrieve the pair elements

To retrieve the pair elements, you need to be able to feed it with a *callback* function, that why you need `f`.

> The `pair` is represented as a function that takes a function argument. When given its argument it will apply the argument to the two components of the pair.